# Can I use Grub on USB2.0 drive to boot a non-bootable USB 3.1 drive?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-drive

I've got a USB 3.1 (ASM1142) card that I'd like to boot from.  The card doesn't supporting booting, on its own, but I'm wondering if I could boot Grub2 from a USB 2.0 device and 'hand off' booting of the system to the USB 3.1 card.

Comment: Just set the `bootable flag` to the usb devices's partition containing a linux installation, run `update-grub` on your hard drive and let us know if it appears in the boot menu.

Comment: I'm using CentOS - no update-grub for me :)

Comment: possibly be the same as `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`